# asp.net mvc 5.0 dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have added a controller with following code.

```cs
TestDBEntities db = new TestDBEntities();

public ActionResult Populate()
{
    var data = from d in db.Depts select d;
    SelectList li = new SelectList(data, "DeptCode", "DeptName");
    ViewData["departments"] = li;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Populate(FormCollection form)
{
    var str = form["departments"];
    ViewBag.d = str;
    var data = from d in db.Depts select d;
    SelectList li = new SelectList(data, "DeptCode", "DeptName",str);
    ViewData["departments"] = li;
    return View();
}
```

also added a view for above action method 'Populate' as below markup

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm("Populate","Department", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    @Html.DropDownList("departments", (SelectList)ViewData["departments"], "Select Dept", new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
    <p>@ViewBag.d</p>
}
```

When i select the value from dropdownlist, it shows the selected value. but does not persist the dropdown selection.

Please suggest the correction. And also please let me know how i can write `HttpPost` method efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the property your binding to and the `SelectList` different names. Your attempting to bind the selected value to a `ViewData` property named `departments` which is is typeof `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` but a `<select>` element can only bind to a simple value (`int`, `string` etc).

Internally what is happening when you return the view in the POST method is

1. The `DropDownList()` method gets the value of the property your
   binding to, which in you case is `"System.Meb.Mvc.SelectList"` (the
   `.ToString()` value of `ViewData["departments"]`)
2. Because the value of the property your binding to is not `null`, a
   new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is generated from the one you
   provided. Because none of the options in your `SelectList` match
   `"System.Meb.Mvc.SelectList"` then the `Selected` property is not
   set so the first option is selected because something has to be.

Note that setting the 4th parameter in the `SelectList` constructor is ignored by the `DropDownList()` (and `DropDownListFor()`) method except when the value of the first parameter is `null`

To do this correctly, start by creating a view model to represent what you want to display/edit and strongly bind to you model.

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a department")]
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public SelectList DepartmentList { get; set; }
}
```

and the associated view will be

```cs
@model MyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Department)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Department, Model.DepartmentList, "Select Department")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Department)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

and the controller methods will be

```cs
public ActionResult Populate()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Populate(MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
    // Save and redirect.
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(MyModel model)
{
    model.DepartmentList = new SelectList(db.Depts, "DeptCode", "DeptName");
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply.  but i want to do this without using model in a simple way.

Comment: What? How much simpler do you want. And what do you mean _without using model_?

Comment: means without creating a new viewmodel class i.e. MyModel.

Comment: also thanks for the explanation. it helped me a lot.